# Algorithm To create hierarchy Dropdown

Tags: c#, html, algorithm

I am creating a dynamic HTML division which is having drop down content as an hierarchy based on value received from database.
I will give an example based on value i am  receiving from database.
Result Set

```
ID  Name  ParentID
7   A      2
8   B      7
9   C      7
10  D      7
11  E      2
12  F      2
14  G      7
```

For this Html generated should be

```
<ul>
   <li> A 
        <ul>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
            <li>G</li>
       </ul>

   </li>
   <li>E</li>
   <li>F</li>
</ul>
```

Can someone suggest algorithm to achieve this kind of result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a code in Java, but I think it won't be a problem for you to write the C# code. You can test my code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMTk81ay1JWU5ReEU). The idea is to map your result set on a hierarchy represented with next classes.

Node class:

```
class Node {
    private String name;
    private List<Node> children;

    Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void addChild(Node child) {
        children.add(child);
    }

    List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Some helper class just for the sake of clean code:

```
class Tag {
    private String open;
    private String close;

    Tag(String open, String close) {
        this.open = open;
        this.close = close;
    }

    String open() {
        return open;
    }

    String close() {
        return close;
    }
}
```

Hierarchy emulation (I also added additional levels for demonstration):

```
private static List<Node> createHierarchy() {
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    Node nodeA = new Node("A");
    Node nodeB = new Node("B");
    Node nodeC = new Node("C");
    Node nodeD = new Node("D");
    Node nodeE = new Node("E");
    Node nodeF = new Node("F");
    Node nodeG = new Node("G");
    Node node1 = new Node("1");
    Node node2 = new Node("2");
    Node node3 = new Node("3");
    Node node4 = new Node("4");
    nodeA.addChild(nodeB);
    nodeA.addChild(nodeC);
    nodeD.addChild(node1);
    nodeD.addChild(node2);
    node2.addChild(node3);
    node2.addChild(node4);
    nodeA.addChild(nodeD);
    nodeA.addChild(nodeE);
    nodes.add(nodeA);
    nodes.add(nodeF);
    nodes.add(nodeG);
    return nodes;
}
```

And a main logic. I used a recursion to traverse my data structure:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printHierarchy(createHierarchy(), new StringBuilder());
}

private static void printHierarchy(List<Node> nodes, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    stringBuilder.append(ul.open());
    for (Node node : nodes) {
        printNode(node, stringBuilder);
        printChildren(node.getChildren(), stringBuilder);
        stringBuilder.append(li.close());
    }
    stringBuilder.append(ul.close());
    System.out.print(stringBuilder.toString());
}

private static void printNode(Node node, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    stringBuilder.append(li.open()).append(node);
}

private static void printChildren(List<Node> children, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    if (children.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    stringBuilder.append(ul.open());
    for (Node child : children) {
        stringBuilder.append(li.open()).append(child);
        if (child.getChildren().size() > 0) {
            printChildren(child.getChildren(), stringBuilder);
        }
        stringBuilder.append(li.close());
    }
    stringBuilder.append(ul.close());
}
```

Result:

```
<ul>
  <li>A
    <ul>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D
        <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2
            <ul>
              <li>3</li>
              <li>4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>E</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with ParentID = null.

Get all items where ParentID matches your ParentID, check if there is more than one item for the next sublevel; if there is, wrap them in a -tag.

Then iterate through all items you got, append the item and handle their sublevels recursively.

You reach an endnode if you do not get any more items that match your ParentID.

Also, do not forget to close your opened -tags.